# draw a square matrix

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to make a game where I need a square shaped matrix with 6 row and six columns. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iPhone compatible version of Apple's Geek Game Board sample code:
https://bitbucket.org/snej/geekgameboard/.

The original version can be found here (Mac only):
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GeekGameBoard/Introduction/Intro.html

It's using Core Animation and provides reusable classes for your problem.